# Setting up ADT Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt

I'm going crazy here trying to set up ADT Eclipse!!!!! (<- as evidenced by the overuse of exclamation marks)

All I want is to run the basic HelloWorld example without any LogCat errors, which works when I run it for the first time right after installing, but after I restart the PC, I get TONS of errors. The program will still run, but in more complicated projects, I don't know whether the app crashed because of me or because of a bad setup.

Here are the things I've tried:

- lots of different test configurations (AVDs with different settings as well as using my actual phone)
- removing API19 and using API18 instead
- [on my multi-user PC] using the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME and user.home in the Preferences
- 32 and 64 bit versions, single and multi-user Windows 7 installations (I even did a fresh 32bit Win7 installation with a single user)...usually I have my home folder on D: but I also tried a user with the default settings
- crying in the corner and hoping the errors will go away by themselves or it's all just a bad dream

The end result is always the same, it might work the first time, but then I end up with lots of errors when running the project.

So I would really appreciate some help on this, either by pointing me to what I'm doing wrong or a step-by-step guide on how to set ADT up.

Here is the complete error log from the HelloWorld project (though it looks different when trying it on an actual phone, where I get lots of different errors):

```
12-11 07:11:42.541: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(275): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
12-11 07:11:42.862: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-11 07:11:46.991: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
12-11 07:11:46.991: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
12-11 07:11:47.221: E/EventHub(275): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-11 07:11:47.221: E/EventHub(275): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-11 07:11:47.981: E/MobileDataStateTracker(275): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
12-11 07:11:47.991: E/MobileDataStateTracker(275): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
12-11 07:11:52.800: E/LocationManagerService(275): no geocoder provider found
12-11 07:11:52.820: E/LocationManagerService(275): no geofence provider found
12-11 07:11:55.280: E/BluetoothAdapter(346): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:55.280: E/BluetoothAdapter(346): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:55.571: E/BluetoothAdapter(346): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:55.651: E/BluetoothAdapter(442): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:56.691: E/BluetoothAdapter(407): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:56.931: E/BluetoothAdapter(442): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:57.771: E/BluetoothAdapter(407): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:11:57.911: E/cutils-trace(492): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-11 07:11:57.971: E/BluetoothAdapter(346): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:02.541: E/BluetoothAdapter(346): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:03.551: E/BluetoothAdapter(442): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:04.261: E/BluetoothAdapter(275): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:04.261: E/BluetoothAdapter(275): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:04.371: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-11 07:12:04.381: E/SoundPool(275): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-11 07:12:12.357: E/ConnectivityService(275): startUsingNetworkFeature took too long: 4250ms
12-11 07:12:12.627: E/logwrapper(686): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-11 07:12:12.647: E/SecondaryTablController(34): ip route add failed: /system/bin/ip route add 10.0.2.2/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 table 60
12-11 07:12:12.657: E/ConnectivityService(275): Exception trying to add a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '11 interface route add eth0 secondary 10.0.2.2 32 0.0.0.0' failed with '400 11 ip route modification failed (No such device)'
12-11 07:12:12.667: E/logwrapper(687): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-11 07:12:12.707: E/SecondaryTablController(34): ip route add failed: /system/bin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 table 60
12-11 07:12:12.707: E/ConnectivityService(275): Exception trying to add a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '12 interface route add eth0 secondary 0.0.0.0 0 10.0.2.2' failed with '400 12 ip route modification failed (No such device)'
12-11 07:12:13.687: E/SQLiteLog(615): (1) no such table: Account
12-11 07:12:17.247: E/BluetoothAdapter(442): Bluetooth binder is null
12-11 07:12:18.917: E/logwrapper(752): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-11 07:12:18.937: E/SecondaryTablController(34): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 10.0.2.2/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 table 60
12-11 07:12:18.957: E/logwrapper(754): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-11 07:12:18.977: E/SecondaryTablController(34): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 table 60
12-11 07:12:20.887: E/cutils-trace(765): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Thank you in advance for your help! I'm really frustrated because I'm really looking forward to develop my own programs.

Comment: is your application crashes..?

Comment: If these errors doesn't affect your app process, ignore them.

Comment: So just to clarify... you guys have those errors as well when running a program?

Answer (score 1):

Those are not your errors, but errors of different system services. You can set a filter to the LogCat, so you'll only see errors from your application:

[image]

In Eclipse you just have to click on the little '+' symbol on the left side of the stack trace.

Of course, filtering the LogCat by application is also possible in IntelliJ/Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick and elaborate answer!
However, how do I know that those errors do not affect my actual program? For example, the error "SQLiteLog - (1) no such table: files" does seem kind of important to me...